# R - get all the calendar years between two dates

Tags: r, date, calendar, dataframe

I have a data frame which contains a column with start dates and a column with end dates. I was wondering if there is a decent, R way, from base-R to get all the calendar years between those two dates (inclusive).

I have a workaround

```
seq(as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$start[1]), '%Y')), 
      as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$end[1]), '%Y')), by = 1)
```

But I would like something that I can pass the entire vector to.

I guess I can use `apply` if I pass the `seq` function in it, but is it the way to go? The end result I am trying to reach is a histogram of how many entries are "active" per calendar year. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a yearly sequence:

```
sd = as.Date("1990-01-01")
ed = as.Date("1995-01-01")

substr(seq(sd, ed, "years"), 1, 4)
```

which gives you the output `[1] "1990" "1991" "1992" "1993" "1994" "1995"`

## Edit:

You can wrap this in a function and use `mapply` such that you can pass the whole vector.

```
sd = as.Date(c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1993-01-01", "1992-01-01"))
ed = as.Date(c("1995-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", "1998-01-01"))

yearser = function(sd, ed){
    substr(seq(sd, ed, "years"), 1, 4)
}

mapply(function(x, y) yearser(x, y), sd, ed)
```

Of course, this approach with `mapply` would also work with your original workaround.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Well, this part I have already figured it out. True that you use `substr` instead of coercing/formatting like I do, we reach the same result, but the thing is the date formats differ between the databases, so it has to be kept more general. Any idea how I can apply it on entire vectors?

Comment: I edited the post such that the function can be applied to vectors.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Now I just need to create a "truth table" with the number of columns being the longest sequence between `sd` and `ed`, something like:
    `min_year = as.numeric(format(as.Date(min(as.vector(sd))), '%Y'))
    max_year = as.numeric(format(as.Date(max(as.vector(ed))), '%Y'))
    min_max = seq(min_year, max_year, by = 1)`
and pass it to your function:
  `yearser = function(seq_min_max, sd, ed)
{
  min_max %in% seq(as.numeric(format(as.Date(sd), '%Y')), 
      as.numeric(format(as.Date(ed), '%Y')), by = 1)
  }`

Comment: I choose your answer as the correct one for making it applicable on vectors and the use of `mapply`. Thank you